# What does someone have to do if he/she masturbate while in fast state during Ramadan?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, masturbation, kaffarah

A sister masturbates as a habit right from childhood, even during Ramadan. She can't control herself even if she didn't have the intention of doing it, even though she knows recently (like 2 years ago) that it's haraam, it has been going on for over 10 years.

1. Does she need to repay up her Ramadan fast or not, that no matter how hard she tries to avoid this, yet proves abortive.
2. Will ALLAH accept her fasting whenever she did the act she continues her fast, that the addiction she can't control it.

Answer (score 1):

Masturbation is Haram in Ramadan or any other time, but it is worse in Ramadan. Then, it spoils one's fasting in Ramadan and necessitates making up that day without paying kaffara, but not if it happens at night.

- [Source English](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85599)
- [Source Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/75091)

Answer (score 0):

Ejaculation by a means other than coitus (entering the penis in the vagina\anus) comes under the ruling of masturbation. This applies to masturbation of oneself or by means of another person (such as the various types of non-penetrative sex).

You need to do the following:

**Tawbah:** Masturbating during Ramadan is haram. You should feel shame and remorse and should correct your behavior in the future. If it is unavoidable then limit it to the night time, there can be no excuse for doing it during the fasting hours.

**Ghusl:** It creates ritual impurity and requires taking a bath. This is essential before you can perform the daily prayers etc.

**Qada:** It breaks the fast making it invalid. Hence you are required to repeat that fast after Ramadan.

**Imsak:** While it broke the fast, you are still expected to refrain from food, drink and sexual pleasure for the rest of the day, in respect of Ramadan.

**Kaffarah:** Whether breaking the fast by masturbation requires Kaffarah is disagreed upon. According to the Hanafis, Shafi'is and Hanbalis it does not require Kaffarah. While according to the Malikis and one saying of the Hanbalis it requires Kaffarah. The Kaffarah of breaking a fast (if it is applicable) is to free a slave, or to fast consecutively for 60 days, or to feed 60 people for a day.

**Ref:**

> تعمد إنزال المني بلا جماع، وذلك كالاستمناء بالكف أو بالتبطين والتفخيذ، أو باللمس والتقبيل ونحوهما فإنه يوجب القضاء دون الكفارة عند جمهور الفقهاء - الحنفية والشافعية والحنابلة - وعند المالكية يوجب القضاء والكفارة معا
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/17386#p1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Masturbation is Haraam, and the sin is even greater when done in Ramadhaan. The fast will break and you will have to make Qadha of the fasts that were broken without Kaffarah.

Comment: This answer does not meet our quality standards. Please edit your answer to include some Islamic sources that back up your answer. For more information on how to answer a question well, please see our [How to Answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/answering) Guide

Answer (score -3):

If you read the Quran, Allah in Surah al-Baqarah allows the believers to sleep with their legal women at night, of course it is good to be clean before noon as a practice, else the fast might be makrooh / adulterated or unaccepted.

I don't think during daylight hours, one can indulge and get away. I have never heard a scholar approve it. It sounds like this lady has to give up the endeavor of fasting all together and pay the kaffara, because one really can't be in a state  of fast, be eating, or indulging in a sexual activity.

One might do well to reach out to a *Faqih* who understands fiqh and ask him this question.