# Do I have to pay fidya (ransom) for masturbating during the night in Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, sin, masturbation

I have been masturbating at night during Ramadan. I ensure I do *Ghusul* afterwards, but do I also have to pay some *Fidya* or ransom?  Also, does the sin increase if it's done *during* Ramadan?should i do Ghusul before sehri or can i do it in the morning

Comment: See also: [What does someone have to do if he/she msaturbate while in fast state during Ramadan?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24959/9123)  & [repent & seeking forgiveness after cumming out during fast in ramadan](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11129/9123)

Comment: Brotha, it is recommended not to directly tell sins to others. This shows a contempt towards God according to a hadith. Better ask the question in a general way.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not masturbation is considered a sin, it does not invalidate a fast unless one performs it within the time of the fast, i.e. between dawn and maghrib(sunset). Since the fast is not invalidated there is no Kaffarah or Fidyah.

A fast is invalidated by the following actions if done **intentionally** and **during the time of the fast**:

1. eating\vomiting or injecting into the body
2. performing sexual intercourse or ejaculating

It is perfectly acceptable to have intercourse at night just like its acceptable to freely eat at night.

> [Quran 2:187](http://legacy.quran.com/2/187) It has been made permissible for you the night
>   preceding fasting to go to your wives [for sexual relations]. They are
>   clothing for you and you are clothing for them. Allah knows that you
>   used to deceive yourselves, so He accepted your repentance and forgave
>   you. So now, have relations with them and seek that which Allah has
>   decreed for you. And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn
>   becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night]. Then
>   complete the fast until the sunset. And do not have relations with
>   them as long as you are staying for worship in the mosques. These are
>   the limits [set by] Allah , so do not approach them. Thus does Allah
>   make clear His ordinances to the people that they may become
>   righteous.

Unintentionally eating during the day, or ejaculating because of a wet dream for example do not break the fast.

Reference on Masturbating at Night in Ramadhan: https://islamqa.info/en/37673

Answer (score 0):

Masturbating is generally haram and a sin in ramdan, and in other months. And no, a ransome is not required, only a kaffara (fasting two month consequently, or feeding 60 poor people) is required for  a married couple who had a sexual intercourse while fasting in ramadan, however, if you do masturbate while fasting in ramadan morning, you will have to fast the day you masturbated in again after ramadan, as masturbation (with or without hands) spoils fasting. You have to repent from this nasty habit as soon as possible my brother, as it has many side effects concerning health. In addition, it is just a very small amount of pleasure, and doesn't deserve spending time doing it, perhaps you'll die wal eyathu bellah while doing it. so why take such risk? 
Wallahu aa'lam

Comment: Please provide some references for your answer.