# If I broke 38 fasts by masturbating, do I need to make up for 60 times this number of days?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, shafii, masturbation

I am a 24 year old unmarried male. I do not come from an Islamic Background. 90% of my knowledge comes from online classes and books. Like many young men, I am seriously addicted to masturbation. I did not know know it was a sin until a few years ago. I try my best to control my urges. But I fail many times. It is an ongoing battle. I have understood that many of my fasts  in Ramdan have gone invalid, because of this action. Over the last few years, I have made a note of the fasts I broke. I broke 38 fasts in total so far. Initially I thought I would make up for them, later in life. Now I know that I have to make up for them at the earliest. I have been doing some research and found that, I have 3 options to make expiation (Kuffarah) for each invalid fast:

```
Free a slave
Fast for 60 days consecutively
Feed 60 poor people with one 'mud' (approx 700-750 grams) food.
```

Source of Info: https://archive.org/details/RulingsOfRamadanInShafiMadhhab

I have started earning now. I am planning to give 700-750 grams of wheat flour everyday to one poor person over the course of 60 days. Since I have lost 38 fasts, for 38*60 = 2280 days (nearly 6 and half years) I will have to keep this up. This is a huge task. I am ashamed to ask a scholar face to face about this issue. Could you please tell me, if I am doing the right thing as per Shafi Madhab?

Comment: You can find some answers here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24959/repent-seeking-forgiveness-after-cumming-out-during-fast-in-ramadan

Comment: and here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11129/what-does-someone-have-to-do-if-he-she-msaturbate-while-in-fast-state-during-ram

Comment: What you are quoting is the kafara for somebody who had intercourse during Ramadan and was fully aware of that. Or according some madhabs of somebody who ate on the day of Ramadan intentionally without any excuse. If you didn't know something you might either re-fast the given days before the next Ramadan or just repent and never do it again, but this is more or less an assumption of mine therefore not posted as an answer.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] and [meta] to learn about this site.

Answer (score -1):

I'm "happy" to say that your theoretic calculation is wrong... Because the 60 day kuffarah is obliged only once and not for each year.

It is not 38 * 60 = 2280 days

For example; you have broken fasts in the year 2015, 2016 and 2017. The number of the broken days does not matter. Lets consider 10 days in total. So you have to fast in total = 10 + 60 days = 70 days

Or lets say totally 90 days broken in the year 2015-2016-2017 so you have a total of 90 + 60 days = 150 days to fast.

Comment: Please provide sources for your answer